# run a command on the remote machine after ssh login

Tags: linux, ssh

I would like to switch to the bash environment after ssh login. Currently I have to type `bash` every time and then `cd` to my working directory.

Where can I add some settings so it will run automatically for me.

Comment: Get the super user to change the shell that you are using.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 1):

There's an environment variable `SHELL` that is set to the current shell. You can set it to your preferred shell by running

```
$ export SHELL=/path/to/shell
```

In order to find the path to your preferred shell just run following command

```
$ whereis bash
```

Enter the path returned by `whereis` command as your shell path.

There's a .profile(`ls -al`) or bash_profile that you can add your setting there. If you can't find such a file then create one using `touch .profile`. (I did create this file on OS X.)

Open the .profile in order to edit it using whatever text editors that you want

```
$ vim .profile
```

Then change the $HOME environment variable in order to change your default home directory path. Enter below line in opened file

```
export HOME=/your/path
```

Save the file

```
:w
```